# How to get the public url of a file?

Tags: pythonanywhere

My problem is that I want to be able to **upload** a PHP file to my **pythonanywhere** server and then get its public url and use it to get notifications from a **webhook** to that url or specifically to the file responsible for processing those notifications. But I can't find a way to get this url and being honest is the first time I find myself using this server. Thank you and excuse my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

PythonAnywhere does not support PHP.